# Windows 11 Single Language: как добавить язык ввода?

Tags: windows, клавиатура, локализация, windows-11, смена-языка

На ноутбуке стоит Windows 11 Single Language. Язык интерфейса - русский. И поменять на другой нельзя. Так же в настройках под выбором языка интерфейса написано "Ваша лицензия Windows поддерживает только один язык интерфейса". Однако ещё ниже я вижу два языка - английский и русский. Насколько я понимаю - это языки ввода, а не интерфейса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникла необходимость добавить ввод на китайском языке. Нажимаю кнопку "Добавить язык". Нахожу китайский. Нажимаю "Далее". Он выдает надпись "Ваша лицензия Windows поддерживает только один язык интерфейса". Но мне не нужен язык интерфейса! Мне нужна раскладка клавиатуры!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно добавить ещё одну раскладку клавиатуры?

Comment: Проблема забавная, но я бы просто поставил нормальную винду (или линукс - чтобы не платить и не пиратить).

Comment: "я бы просто поставил нормальную винду" - такая установлена на ноутбук изначально. Возиться с покупкой лицензии и переустановкой не хочется. Тем более, часто может понадобиться искать и устанавливать очень специфичные драйвера от производителя. Я как-то пробовал переустанавливать Windows на GPD Pocket - там инструкция по установке драйверов на несколько страниц.
Линукс тоже не вариант, так как Винда нужна для работы.

Comment: Комп компу рознь. Если это не что-то сильно необычное, то руками ничего не надо будет делать.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Оказывается надо было выключить все флажки в окне добавления языковых компонентов (распознавание речи, текст в речь, рукописный ввод). В этом случае добавление происходит успешно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]